# Why special characters are automatically turning to someother characters in a string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My actual charcters:

```
ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ
```

Above characters automatically turns into

```
â€™'â€˜Ã†ÃÆŽÆÆÆ”Ä²ÅŠÅ’áºžÃžÇ·ÈœÃ¦Ã°ÇÉ™É›É£Ä³Å‹Å“Ä¸Å¿ÃŸÃ¾Æ¿ÈÄ„ÆÃ‡ÄÆŠÄ˜Ä¦Ä®Æ˜ÅÃ˜Æ ÅžÈ˜Å¢ÈšÅ¦Å²Æ¯YÌ¨Æ³Ä…É“Ã§Ä‘É—Ä™Ä§Ä¯Æ™Å‚Ã¸Æ¡ÅŸÈ™Å£È›Å§Å³Æ°yÌ¨Æ´ÃÃ€Ã‚Ã„ÇÄ‚Ä€ÃƒÃ…ÇºÄ„Ã†Ç¼Ç¢ÆÄ†ÄŠÄˆÄŒÃ‡ÄŽá¸ŒÄÆŠÃÃ‰ÃˆÄ–ÃŠÃ‹ÄšÄ”Ä’Ä˜áº¸ÆŽÆÆÄ ÄœÇ¦ÄžÄ¢Æ”Ã¡Ã Ã¢Ã¤ÇŽÄƒÄÃ£Ã¥Ç»Ä…Ã¦Ç½Ç£É“Ä‡Ä‹Ä‰ÄÃ§Äá¸Ä‘É—Ã°Ã©Ã¨Ä—ÃªÃ«Ä›Ä•Ä“Ä™áº¹ÇÉ™É›Ä¡ÄÇ§ÄŸÄ£É£Ä¤á¸¤Ä¦IÃÃŒÄ°ÃŽÃÇÄ¬ÄªÄ¨Ä®á»ŠÄ²Ä´Ä¶Æ˜Ä¹Ä»ÅÄ½Ä¿Ê¼NÅƒNÌˆÅ‡Ã‘Å…ÅŠÃ“Ã’Ã”Ã–Ç‘ÅŽÅŒÃ•Åá»ŒÃ˜Ç¾Æ Å’Ä¥á¸¥Ä§Ä±Ã­Ã¬iÃ®Ã¯ÇÄ­Ä«Ä©Ä¯á»‹Ä³ÄµÄ·Æ™Ä¸ÄºÄ¼Å‚Ä¾Å€Å‰Å„nÌˆÅˆÃ±Å†Å‹Ã³Ã²Ã´Ã¶Ç’ÅÅÃµÅ‘á»Ã¸Ç¿Æ¡Å“Å”Å˜Å–ÅšÅœÅ ÅžÈ˜á¹¢áºžÅ¤Å¢á¹¬Å¦ÃžÃšÃ™Ã›ÃœÇ“Å¬ÅªÅ¨Å°Å®Å²á»¤Æ¯áº‚áº€Å´áº„Ç·Ãá»²Å¶Å¸È²á»¸Æ³Å¹Å»Å½áº’Å•Å™Å—Å¿Å›ÅÅ¡ÅŸÈ™á¹£ÃŸÅ¥Å£á¹­Å§Ã¾ÃºÃ¹Ã»Ã¼Ç”Å­Å«Å©Å±Å¯Å³á»¥Æ°áºƒáºÅµáº…Æ¿Ã½á»³Å·Ã¿È³á»¹Æ´Åº
```

I got that output when i tried to console.log the string

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Please check this link for my code https://jsfiddle.net/tz0c2xa9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code line, add between html head tags.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not exactly a question, but it's obvious your file encodings are not what you expect them to be. Make sure everything is UTF-8 through and through.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1 - UTF-8 vs ANSI

Your first block is in UTF-8 format, and the second is encoded by ANSI.
Somewhere during your translation process, the strings changed from UTF-8 to ANSI. Make sure all your text sources are saved in UTF-8.
You can check with a free text editor like Notepad++ .

#### 2 - Understand Javascript String codes

Each char has a given code, independently of what you think it's there.
For "special" chars, what it looks like a `A` might contain a different code from the default `A`.

A small example:

```js
var letter1 = String.fromCharCode(65); // output: "A"
var letter2 = String.fromCharCode(913); // output: "Α"
console.log(letter1);
console.log(letter2);
console.log(letter1 === letter2);
```

So when you apply any logic to a string it will not give you the result you are expecting when the char code is not exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you yar, I understood